# Socket timeout while updating Oracle table

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a strange problem with Spring Batch. I have a project which sets up a reader and a writer to the same table. The reader performs a select and the writer performs an update of the rows read. I use one of the columns as an index to allow me to select a range of rows.

reader: (using JdbcPagingItemReader, fetchsize=5000, commitinteval=100)
select c1,c2,c3,index from table where index>= :fromId and index <=:toId

writer: (using JdbcBatchItemWriter)
update table set c1:=val,c2:=val,c3:=val where index=:index

I am using a partitioner and injecting the fromId and toId in the partitioner listener.

it seems to work ok for a small number of rows but when I have more than around 100 I get a socket timeout on the writer.

I can include complete code if required but I think this is a basic misunderstanding on my part regarding how Spring operates.

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Could you put stack trace and code?

Comment: How long is a chunk taking?  It's common for firewalls to kill persistent connections after a given period of time.  You may want to make sure a firewall isn't killing your database connection while your chunk is processing.

Answer (score 0):

forgot to answer this - seems the problem was related to my spring config - solved by setting connector bean with correct DB pool values